# Any dictionary/glossary resource for VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am trying to switch to Blender after having a little bit of experience using other video editing software and ideally would not like to spend too much time on watching all the lengthy youtube tutorials, rather I prefer to find brief instructions about common tasks in the Docs. The problem is that every software uses its own terminology, and it took me some time to find, for example, that what I would call a *track* in another software is called *channel* in Blender, *fragment* is called *strip*, *cursor* is *playhead* (what?!) etc etc - it makes it much harder to search for the right keywords in documentation and forums. Surprisingly, in the [official Glossary](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html), none of these terms are present! Is there any other resource available for that kind of information?

Comment: The manual of the vse is far from comprehensive. To get started, I would recommend you to watch a tutorial like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXs21UilNYQ

I like your approach. If you at some point would like to improve on the Glossary list or the VSE docs, you can get in touch with the module owner here: https://blender.chat/channel/vse

Comment: My advice is that you find a dedicated video editor and use that instead of blender. Blender's VSE is not as robust or responsive, efficient  or friendly as other editors out there.

Comment: yep, would agree with everything @susu said, emphasising that it's very unintuitive, sluggish and with the worst rendering times ever, but also adding the caveat that if you're on linux, it's the most stable and frame-accurate video editor you can get, personally I can't imagine using anything else.

Comment: @wilks davinci resolve free works just fine in linux...

Comment: @susu i've used it before but couldn't get the latest versions to even start. i also like flowblade a lot but still think it isn't as reliable as blender